# Trigger a single from outside the create closure?

Tags: rx-swift

I'm new to all of this, so apologies if my RX terminology is a bit off.

So I would like to implement an observable which emits only once when a system callback is received.  Basically the idea is that by subscribing to this observable, it would be guaranteed that the system event has already occurred when the subscription closure is executed.  It may be executed immediately if the system event already happened, or it may be deferred until the event occurs, or never execute if the system callback is never executed.

It seems like a Single is a reasonable fit for the use-case, since it's intended to be a one-time observable which either succeeds or fails.  But it appears a completable's `success` callback can only be triggered from inside `Single.create {}`.

I created a workaround by subscribing to a single inside the create closure, but it feels like a hack:

```
class MyClass {

    private var systemCallbackSubject = AsyncSubject<Bool>()

    var isReady : Single<Void> {
        let single = Single<Bool>.create { single in
            self.systemCallbackSubject.subscribe(onCompleted: {
                single(.success(()))
            }, onDisposed: nil)
            return Disposables.create {}
        }
        return  single
    }

    func onSystemEventCallback() {
        systemCallbackSubject.onCompleted()
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation does not seem to match the desired behaviour. If I understand correctly, you are willing to subscribe multiple times and get result only when and if the event happened.

In this case I would use a *BehaviorSubject* without initial value. Every time you subscribe to it, it will return the latest value, if present. If it changes after subscription, change will be received. If you want strictly 1 attempt, add 
*.take(1)*. You can also convert it to Single by adding *.take(1).toSingle()*

Or perhaps something with *.replay(1)*

Comment: Thank you, this is much cleaner